# Java matcher not matching even conditioned to find() in a loop

Tags: java, regex

**Introduction**

I want to extract a substring inside a String using RegEx in Java. For such, lets use Pattern and Matcher classes to do it properly.

**Code**

```
package stringlearning;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
 *
 * @author Jonathan
 */
public class StringLearning {

    //Example String
    public static String line = "This is the (first|second|third) choice.";


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        //String is right, right?
        System.out.println("Line is: " + line);

        //How to use RegEx in Java properly
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\(([^\\)]+)\\)", Pattern.DOTALL);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);

        //While we find, keep looping
        while(matcher.find())
        {
            //What we foud out?
            System.out.println(matcher.matches());
            System.out.println(matcher.groupCount());
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }



    }

}
```

**Problem**

I still can't understand why it can't find anything. The regular expression was made on [RegEx](http://regexr.com/4kdp1) and works properly there *(Do not forget about the escapes! '/')*

**I want to know what I am missing that it doesn't match**

**Notes**

- IDE: NetBeans
- Java version is 1.8.0_221

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is in this line inside the `while` loop:

```
System.out.println(matcher.matches());
```

Here `matches()` attempts to match the entire region against the pattern.

If the match succeeds then more information can be obtained via the `start`, `end`, and `group` methods.

Since your regex doesn't match entire input, `matches()` returns `false` and you will get `java.lang.IllegalStateException` where code calls `.group(1)`.

To fix just comment out `System.out.println(matcher.matches());` line and rerun the code.

btw you can use this shorter regex:

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\(([^)]+)\\)");
```

As there is no need to escape `)` inside the character class and `DOTALL` is redundant here since you're not using DOT anywhere in your regex.